# CSS grid does not place items created with React and array.map

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-grid

I am working on a React challenge to create a calculator. I render the buttons using React functional components and I plan to place them in the right place using a CSS grid.

I rendered some buttons directly:

```
const Equals = () => {
  return (
    <button id="equals" type="button" className="btn btn-success"> = </button>
  )
};
```

and I can easily place them wherever I want in the CSS grid layout using `grid-area`.

But I can't place any button created with an `array.map`, like these:

```
return (
  <div id='num-pad' className="btn-group" role="group">
    {
      numbers.map(ele => 
        <button id={ele.letter} key={ele.letter} className="btn btn-secondary"> 
          {ele.number} 
        </button>
      )
    }
  </div>
)
```

Why is it?

Here is the link to my pen:
https://codepen.io/simone-saimon-rossi/pen/LYbQWyr

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `display: grid`, this only affects the direct children of that element. You are wrapping all of the buttons with another `<div>`, which means the only direct children of `#calculator` are `#equals`, `#clear`, `#num-pad`, and `#ops-pad`. What you need to do is get rid of these wrapping divs and make them all direct children of `#calculator`.

i.e. change this:

```
return (
  <div id='num-pad' className="btn-group" role="group">
    {
      numbers.map(ele => 
        <button id={ele.letter} key={ele.letter} className="btn btn-secondary"> 
          {ele.number} 
        </button>
      )
    }
  </div>
)
```

to this:

```
return (
  <>
    {
      numbers.map(ele => 
        <button id={ele.letter} key={ele.letter} className="btn btn-secondary"> 
          {ele.number} 
        </button>
      )
    }
  </>
)
```

(and similarly for the other ones)

Answer (score 0):

First, what you need to do is render your buttons so that they are all siblings of one another. Then you can add class names for each button to control their placement.

Here is a working example [hosted at CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-calculator-92czh?file=/src/index.js:0-1775).

**Note:** Reusable components should not have IDs associated to them. You should add these IDs when using them, not when defining them. I converted all your IDs to classes.

### First step

Get the buttons to render side-by-side. Convert the wrapping `<div>` tags for each button array with [fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax) tags (`<></>`).

```
const Equals = () => {
  return (
    <button className="equals" type="button" className="btn btn-success">=</button>
  );
};

const Clear = () => {
  return (
    <button className="clear" type="button" className="btn btn-danger">C</button>
  );
};

const Operations = () => {
  const operations = [
    { symbol: "+", letter: "add" },
    { symbol: "-", letter: "subtract" },
    { symbol: "x", letter: "multiply" },
    { symbol: "/", letter: "divide" }
  ];

  return (
    <>
      {operations.map((ele) => (
        <button id={ele.letter} key={ele.letter} className="btn btn-warning">
          {ele.symbol}
        </button>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

const Numbers = () => {
  const numbers = [
    { number: "0", letter: "zero" },
    { number: "1", letter: "one" },
    { number: "2", letter: "two" },
    { number: "3", letter: "three" },
    { number: "4", letter: "four" },
    { number: "5", letter: "five" },
    { number: "6", letter: "six" },
    { number: "7", letter: "seven" },
    { number: "8", letter: "eight" },
    { number: "9", letter: "nine" },
    { number: ".", letter: "decimal" }
  ];

  return (
    <>
      {numbers.map((ele) => (
        <button id={ele.letter} key={ele.letter} className="btn btn-secondary">
          {ele.number}
        </button>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

const Display = () => {
  return <div className="display">C</div>;
};

const Calculator = () => {
  return (
    <div className="calculator">
      <Display />
      <div class="buttons">
        <Equals />
        <Clear />
        <Numbers />
        <Operations />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Calculator />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.calculator {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.display {
  background-color: #d99e36;
  color: #080202;
  font-family: "IBM Plex Mono", monospace;
  height: 2em;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.buttons {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 0.25em;
  padding: 0.25em;
  flex: 1;
}
```

### Second step

Render the buttons where you want. If you have any issues, please refer to: [MDN / CSS / Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout).

```
const Equals = () => {
  return <button className="btn btn-success letter-equals">=</button>;
};

const Clear = () => {
  return <button className="btn btn-danger letter-clear">C</button>;
};

const Operations = () => {
  const operations = [
    { symbol: "+", letter: "add" },
    { symbol: "-", letter: "subtract" },
    { symbol: "×", letter: "multiply" },
    { symbol: "÷", letter: "divide" }
  ];

  return (
    <>
      {operations.map(({ letter, symbol }) => (
        <button key={letter} className={`btn btn-warning letter-${letter}`}>
          {symbol}
        </button>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

const Numbers = () => {
  const numbers = [
    { number: "0", letter: "zero" },
    { number: "1", letter: "one" },
    { number: "2", letter: "two" },
    { number: "3", letter: "three" },
    { number: "4", letter: "four" },
    { number: "5", letter: "five" },
    { number: "6", letter: "six" },
    { number: "7", letter: "seven" },
    { number: "8", letter: "eight" },
    { number: "9", letter: "nine" },
    { number: ".", letter: "decimal" }
  ];

  return (
    <>
      {numbers.map(({ letter, number }) => (
        <button key={letter} className={`btn btn-secondary letter-${letter}`}>
          {number}
        </button>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

const Display = () => {
  return <div className="display">HELLO WORLD</div>;
};

const Calculator = () => {
  return (
    <div className="calculator">
      <Display />
      <div class="buttons">
        <Equals />
        <Clear />
        <Numbers />
        <Operations />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Calculator />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.calculator {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.display {
  background-color: #d99e36;
  color: #080202;
  font-family: "IBM Plex Mono", monospace;
  height: 2em;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.buttons {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 0.25em;
  padding: 0.25em;
  flex: 1;
}

.letter-clear {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.letter-divide {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.letter-multiply {
  grid-column: 4;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.letter-add {
  grid-column: 4;
  grid-row: 3;
}

.letter-subtract {
  grid-column: 4;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.letter-zero {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 5;
}

.letter-one {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 4;
}

.letter-two {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 4;
}

.letter-three {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 4;
}

.letter-four {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 3;
}

.letter-five {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 3;
}

.letter-six {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 3;
}

.letter-seven {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.letter-eight {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.letter-nine {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.letter-decimal {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 5;
}

.letter-equals {
  grid-column: 4;
  grid-row: 4 / 6;
}
```